# Java Swing JColorChooser Color RGB to sRGB

Tags: java, swing, colors, rgb, srgb

Is there a way to use the `JColorChooser` to return a Color that can be converted into their corresponding sRGB float values?

```
Color backgroundColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(this,"Select a color", default);
float r = backgroundColor.getRed();   //Need these to return float color e.g. 0.9333333f
float g = backgroundColor.getGreen(); 
float b = backgroundColor.getBlue();
```

The default `JColorChooser` is fine I just need a way to convert the color it returns into 0 to 1 RGB.

I don't understand how to use the API for [`Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) to make this happen. Could someone please provide a example on how to do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Just divide all values by 255

Comment: No... Give me a second. No way it's that simple.

Comment: @Syncit HOT DAMN! Can't believe it didn't occur to me to do that. I kept thinking there was something in the Color API that needed to happen. Thank you. Submit answer and I will green check it ASAP!

Comment: @boardkeystown, *No way it's that simple* - even simpler, read the `Color` API. The values are returned in a float array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just divide all values by 255 no conversions required